# Why does the formula for population standard deviation not subtract 1 from the N?

Tags: standard-deviation

Why does the formula for population standard deviation not subtract 1 from the N?

Comment: N-1 is used for the sample variance for a sample of size N from an infinite population to get an unbiased estimate.  In a finite population the variance is the sum of square deviations from the population mean divided by the population size N.

Answer (score 1):

We have many posts discussing the relationship between $n$ and $n-1$ denominators in variance, but I don't recall seeing one ask it in quite this way. Search of our site will bring a number of other helpful questions somewhat related to this one.

Imagine you happened to know the population mean when trying to estimate the population variance.

Then you could use that population mean in working out the deviations from the mean. The average of the squared deviations from that mean would be an unbiased estimate of the population variance

Nearly always of course, you don't know the population mean, only the sample mean, but the sample mean is "pulled" nearer to the data than the population mean is; the sums of squares are always at least as small as the calculation using the population mean, so the average squared distance is on average too small.

It turns out that you can exactly adjust for this bias ("too small on average") by replacing the $n$ denominator in variance by $n-1$.

So it's more than the $n$ denominator is the fundamental concept and the $n-1$ replacement ("Bessel's correction") in sample variance is an adjustment for the fact that it would otherwise be too small on average.

Of course when it comes to standard deviation it's no longer unbiased, but people still stick to it.

Comment: I believe the answer is simpler and much more basic: most "populations" are not finite and many finite ones do not have well-defined values of $n$.  They are used as models of sampling.  In sampling with replacement, $n$ could be doubled, tripled, etc., by replicating each object once, twice, etc, without changing the model at all.  If $n-1$ were used in a formula, the "population variance" would not be well-defined.